# App Nexus integration with react-gpt

Tags: reactjs, ads, adsense, google-dfp

we are trying to integrate app nexus(https://www.appnexus.com/en) along with the react-gpt(https://github.com/nfl/react-gpt) library. However, the ads are not being displayed when app nexus is enabled. They display fine when app nexus is disabled.
Following is the sample code for the same, the part of code which displays ads is being implemented using the react-gpt library and not plain js as shown in the following snippet -
https://jsfiddle.net/prebid/bhn3xk2j/458/

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Prebid Config Section START -->
  <!-- Make sure this is inserted before your GPT tag -->
  <script> 
    var PREBID_TIMEOUT = 700;

    var adUnits = [{
        code: 'div-gpt-ad-1460505748561-0',
        sizes: [[300, 250], [300,600]],
        bids: [{
            bidder: 'appnexus',
            params: {
               placementId: '10433394'
            }
        }]
    },{
        code: 'div-gpt-ad-1460505661639-0',
        sizes: [[728, 90], [970, 90]],
        bids: [{
            bidder: 'appnexus',
            params: {
               placementId: '10433394'
            }
        }]
    }];

    var pbjs = pbjs || {};
    pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];

  </script>
  <!-- Prebid Config Section END -->

  <!-- Prebid Boilerplate Section START. No Need to Edit. -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//acdn.adnxs.com/prebid/not-for-prod/prebid.js" async></script>
  <script>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
    });

    pbjs.que.push(function() {
        pbjs.addAdUnits(adUnits);
        pbjs.requestBids({
            bidsBackHandler: sendAdserverRequest
        });
    });

    function sendAdserverRequest() {
        if (pbjs.adserverRequestSent) return;
        pbjs.adserverRequestSent = true;
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            pbjs.que.push(function() {
                pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync();
                googletag.pubads().refresh();
            });
        });
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        sendAdserverRequest();
    }, PREBID_TIMEOUT);

  </script>
  <!-- Prebid Boilerplate Section END -->

  <script>
    (function () {
        var gads = document.createElement('script');
        gads.async = true;
        gads.type = 'text/javascript';
        var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
        gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
        var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
    })();
  </script>

  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
        googletag.defineSlot('/19968336/header-bid-tag-0', [[300, 250], [300, 600]], 'div-gpt-ad-1460505748561-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

        googletag.defineSlot('/19968336/header-bid-tag1', [[728, 90], [970, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1460505661639-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Prebid.js Test</h2>
<h5>Div-1</h5>
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1460505748561-0'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1460505748561-0'); });
    </script>
</div>

<h5>Div-2</h5>
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1460505661639-0'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1460505661639-0'); });
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to why its not working?

Comment: are you sure you posted the right examples? I can't find the code where you're using react-gpt - just common prebid samples that work fine for me

Comment: I have mentioned in the description that I am using the react-gpt code where there is vanilla js for displaying the ads.